# Gaussian filter bug in scipy_filters python

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, scipy

I want to apply a Gaussian filter on an float numpy array using python2.
In fact I'm trying to rewrite the code [Retrospective Correction using Homomorphic Filtering](https://clouard.users.greyc.fr/Pantheon/experiments/illumination-correction/index-en.html) in python,
 `g(x,y) = exp(LPF(log(f(x,y)))) . C`

where LPF(f(x,y)) is the low-pass filter of f(x,y) and C is the normalization coefficient.

Here is my code, which would crash at line:LPFF = scipy_filters.gaussian_filter1d(logF, sigma=10)

```
fxy = greyscale_matrix
logF = np.log1p(fxy)
print logF
LPFF = scipy_filters.gaussian_filter1d(logF, sigma=10)
print LPFF
expF = np.expm1(LPFF)
tmp_div = fxy / expF
meanF_down = np.mean(tmp_div)
meanF_top = np.mean(fxy)
C = meanF_top / meanF_down
gx_matrix = expF * C
rtn_matrix = greyscale_matrix - gx_matrix

Image.fromarray(gx_matrix).show()
Image.fromarray(rtn_matrix).show()
```

I try to debug it, when going to

```
def correlate1d(*args, **kwargs): # real signature unknown
    pass
```

from _nd_image.py the code seems crash with no idea.
I also find a github doing this job as [Implementation of homomorphic filter made in Python](https://github.com/glasgio/homomorphic-filter), but something is wrong with it.

Source img:
[sourceimg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OZFrx.png)

Using this may give me a filtered img like:[filtered img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3fm2o.png)
Of course by changing the attributes I can make it lighter, but the excessive shading trend is obviously still exist.

Could anybody shed some light on this problem? Thx a lot!

Comment: Why are you using a 1D filter in 2D? Is there an error message, or does Python truly crash?

Comment: There is no error message, just crash every time. Sorry im a newbee

Comment: You should be using `scipy.ndimage.filters.gaussian_filter`, but that is implemented in terms of the 1D filter you use, so if that crashes so will this one. Did you try the filter in OpenCV? You can also try PyDIP.

Comment: Which version of scipy are you using?  You can check with `import scipy; print(scipy.__version__)`

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Python 2.7.14 (default, Mar 22 2018, 15:04:47) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.39.2)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import scipy
>>> print scipy.__version__
1.0.0

Answer (score 1):

You don't say which version of SciPy that you are using, but I suspect you are hitting a [bug](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/8207) that should have been fixed in SciPy version 1.0.1 (and 1.1.0).  The bug causes the interpreter to crash when the input to the Gaussian filter function has data type `numpy.float16`.  If your input matrix `fxy` has type `numpy.uint8` (which is typical for an image), then `numpy.log1p(fxy)` returns an array with data type `numpy.float16`, e.g.:

```
In [29]: fxy = np.array([[0, 10], [128, 255]], dtype=np.uint8)

In [30]: logF = np.log1p(fxy)

In [31]: logF
Out[31]: 
array([[0.   , 2.398],
       [4.86 , 5.547]], dtype=float16)
```

`logF` has type `numpy.float16`, and the crash occurs when you pass this to `gaussian_filter1d`.

A quick fix is to convert `fxy` to, say, 64 bit floating point before passing it to `np.log1p`:

```
In [34]: logF = np.log1p(fxy.astype(np.float64))

In [35]: logF.dtype
Out[35]: dtype('float64')
```

Comment: Works for me! THX!